# How do i determine what goes in the model vs controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my most confused aspect that I continually have to ask people about. They have given me answers like 'if it works with data it goes in the model'... but to me that is pretty much ALL of it.

Does anyone have a better way to explain this?

Perfect example from my current code:

I have a listing of posts that can be favorited or not favorited. On the front end, i differentiate the different ones by dynamically adding class="favorite" to the HTML depending on if its a favorite or not.

So basically ... `<li class="item<%= is_favorite?(current_user.id) %>">`

Part of me thinks this should go in the model because its going to be running a statement to  find a record that matches :resource_id and :user_id...

but another part of me thinks its going to be in the controller because its directly outputting the word `" favorite"` which is used in html

My second mini question is, is it the-rails-way to put methods that the controller uses in the same controller? as long as they remain un-routed, etc. Or is that not the right spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking properly.

The right answer is that you should use presenters or decorators.

[See this railscast for inspiration](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper).